Scroll Page Up or Down using Robot Framework
Requirement: I need to select the checkbox w.r.t item name which is available in a web-table. The item name is randomly selected within a range and then the page has to scroll up or down based on the availability of the checkbox to be clicked.
Problem: Able to scroll down to select the checkbox down but not able to scroll up again if the index of the element is above/top of the web-table.
Solution I've Tried so far:

Creating another keyword to scroll based on X & Y positions and using it in place of scroll element into view

Scroll Page
    [Arguments]    ${x}    ${y}
    Execute JavaScript    window.scrollBy(${x}, ${y});


Using Execute JavaScript keyword with scroll to body height
Creating another keyword and scrolling based on window size

Below is the code written so far.
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    Collections
Library    BuiltIn
Library    random

*** Variables ***
${TIMEOUT}    10s
${Item_Name}     //button[contains(@class, 'listing-btn')]

*** Test Cases ***
Select Checkbox wrt Item Name
    ${item_count}    Get Element Count    ${Item_Name}
    ${random_indices}    Evaluate    random.sample(range(${item_count}), 3)    random
    FOR    ${index}    IN    @{random_indices}
        ${item_button_xpath}    Set Variable    (${Item_Button_XPath})[${index+1}]
        ${Item_number}    Get Text    xpath=${Item_button_xpath}
        ${checkbox_xpath}    Set Variable    xpath=//button[normalize-space(text())="${item_number}"]/ancestor::tr//input[@type='checkbox']
        ${element_present}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Page Should Contain Element    ${checkbox_xpath}
        Run Keyword If    '${element_present}' == 'True'    Scroll Element Into View    ${checkbox_xpath}
        Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${checkbox_xpath}    ${TIMEOUT}
        Click Element    ${checkbox_xpath}
    END
    [Return]    ${random_indices}

It would be great if someone can help me out and let me know where I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance...
